# Rename exported Intent Service

Tags: android, intentservice

I have multiple apps on the same device, one of them has an IntentService which gets called from the other apps via:

```
 val intent = Intent()
 intent.component = ComponentName(APP_PACKAGE, INTENT_APP_SERVICE)
 intent.putExtras(key, value)
 context.startService(intent)
```

Everything works as expected.

My question is, what happens when i change the name of the service in the app which exports it?
Do i have to change the **INTENT_APP_SERVICE** to match the new name as well?
Or is there another way to be backwards compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happens when i change the name of the service in the app which exports it?

You are screwed, unless you can somehow force every user to update every one of your apps.

> Do i have to change the INTENT_APP_SERVICE to match the new name as well?

Yes, given the setup that you have.

> Or is there another way to be backwards compatibility?

Step #1: Add an `<intent-filter>` to the `<service>` with a custom `action`

Step #2: Set up your `startService()` `Intent` to use that action, [plus `setPackage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setPackage(java.lang.String)), instead of a `ComponentName`

Now, your service's clients are independent of the name of the service itself, so you can refactor or otherwise rename that service without issue.